# Does subprocess.run() with a cwd argument only work when shell=True on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

On Windows, with the following directory structure:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents
├── bin
│   └── pv.exe
└── dev
    └── script.py
```

And `C:Users\me\Documents\dev` being the working directory of the Python interpreter (v3.8.5):

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\dev> python
>>> import subprocess
```

The following calls to the executable work:

```
>>> subprocess.run(["../bin/pv.exe"])
CompletedProcess(args=['../bin/pv.exe'], returncode=0)
>>> subprocess.run(["pv.exe"], cwd="../bin", shell=True)
CompletedProcess(args=['pv.exe'], returncode=0)
```

But the following call fails:

```
>>> subprocess.run(["pv.exe"], cwd="../bin")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Same results when I use `\\` instead of `/` in paths, or `./pv.exe` instead of `pv.exe`, or an absolute path starting from `C:` for `cwd`. I think I've tried all combinations.

Why is that? The [documentation of the subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) only states that:

> If *cwd* is not `None`, the function changes the working directory to *cwd* before executing the child. *cwd* can be a string, bytes or path-like object. In particular, the function looks for *executable* (or for the first item in *args*) relative to *cwd* if the executable path is a relative path.

1. It doesn't look like it behaves the way it is described.
2. There is no mention of `shell` having to be `True` in the doc. I would like to not use `shell=True`, because I wouldn't touch the `cmd.exe` shell with a barge pole, and the executable name (`pv.exe` in that example) as well as its arguments will actually be user-provided in a more realistic scenario than this MWE (so there are security implications, IIUC).

Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: The docs are misleading. The quoted line pertains only to the POSIX implementation, based on `fork`. The Windows implementation calls `CreateProcessW`, which resolves the executable path in the current process context.

Comment: Even with `shell=True`, you should explicitly reference the working directory as "." in the command line, e.g. `r'.\pv.exe'` (use only backslash in this case, not forward slash). The issue is that implicitly searching the working directory can be excluded from CMD's search (and also that of `CreateProcessW`) by defining an environment variable named [`NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-needcurrentdirectoryforexepathw).

Comment: Also, for POSIX programmers porting code to Windows, do not resolve the executable path from the command line, such as the path that gets parsed as `argv[0]`. A relative path in the command line is relative to the parent's working directory, which may be completely different. The way to resolve the executable path in Windows is via `GetModuleFileNameW` with `NULL` as the module handle.